# Scientists tunnel underground and find albino aliens living in caves

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

Can you help me identify a science fiction movie I saw as a kid?

It was about these scientists who go into underground caves and tunnels where they find these strange,  almost albino aliens living under the ground. I think that the aliens had something to do with the Aztecs or Mayans.

I think it's from either the late 70's or very early 80's. It may even be a TV movie.

Comment: When were you a kid?

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like 1956's [The Mole People](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0049516/):

> A party of archaeologists discovers the remnants of a mutant five-millennia-old Sumerian civilization living beneath a glacier atop a mountain in Mesopatamia.

which can be seen [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AVlcx49t1Hg) or as an episode of Mystery Science Theater 3000 [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dw_1T0RBOg8).

Maybe you saw it as an episode of MST3K in the 90's and remember the time-frame from that. (That's when I first saw it.) Also, it does contain an *albino race* not mentioned in the title or brief IMDb summary. The albino race was *so* light sensitive that one of the explorer's flashlight actually hurt them when pointed their way. The explorers with their different skin and flashlight were thought to be gods for part of the movie. There was also an indiginent beautiful servant woman who was not pale, like the rest, and considered a freak to the society.

Answer (score 6):

[What Waits below](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088392/) with Robert Powell:

> The U.S. government has been using **deep caves in Central America** as bases for a special type of radio transmitter used for communicating with submaries. When the signal from one of these transmitters suddenly disappears, a team of soldiers and **cave specialists** is sent in to find out what happened. After some exploring deep underground, they stumble upon a **tribe of albino cave dwellers** who have been isolated from the rest of the world for thousands of years.

Comment: Cheers, i think this is the film i was thinking of, i remember seeing it many years ago, thanks for putting a name to it.

Answer (score 3):

Its not [the Time Machine](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0054387/) is it? The war era scientist travels forward in time to a place where most of the population have moved underground, thus becoming almost albino savages (morlocks) who conditioned the rest of the people (their food) to head underground at the sound of an air raid siren. It was made in the 60's or 70's.

Comment: The bit about "scientists who go into underground caves and tunnels" made me disqualify The Time Machine. More than one person and more underground exploration. Hopefully one of us has it right and can provide closure to @alan.

Comment: Yeah it kinda threw me off but i thought possibly towards the end where they all go underground. I still agree with you though, i don't think it is Time Machine &)